# computing sum of varchar datatype in a datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, sum

Can Somebody Please help me in computing the sum of a varchar datatype column in a datatable.

I have already tried this:

```
Int32 omarks = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("Sum(Convert(Marks, 'System.Int32'))", ""));
tbobtained.Text = omarks.ToString();
```

But i'm getting this error:

> Syntax Error in Aggregate argument:  Expecting a single column
>   argument with a possible child qualifier.

I will be thankful to the one who helps me about that.

Comment: Please add the appropriate language tag to your question

Comment: which Database you are using...??

Comment: well im using sql server 2008

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `)` is missing for `Sum`

> Sum(Convert(Marks, 'System.Int32')**)**

Comment: yes you are right but having added ) im getting the same error. now my code is Int32 omarks = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("Sum(Convert(Marks, 'System.Int32'))", ""));

Answer (score 1):

You could use CAST:

```
SELECT sum(CAST(MyVarcharCol AS INT)) FROM Table
```

Comment: sorry sevak im having this problem in a DataTable in C#. your answer is fine for sql server but not for a DataTable in C#.Net. Thanks Anyway atleast you tried to help me

Answer (score 1):

Based on the MSDN, have you tried:

```
Int32 omarks = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("Sum(Marks)", ""));
tbobtained.Text = omarks.ToString();
```

The criteria is that the DataColumn `Marks` should be defined as Int32. The first parameter of `Compute` supports aggregation terms but not the **Convert** call that you are making within the `Compute` method.

Comment: code4life brother actually im designing a marks sheet.. I Must have the DataType as Varchar as I want the input of "A" from User if the Student is absent.. I finally had to handle it like this. {int omarks = 0;
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        if (dr["Result"].ToString() != "A")
                        {
                            omarks = omarks + int.Parse(dr["Marks"].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    tbobtained.Text = omarks.ToString();}